# Evaluating the Surface Integral $\iint_{x^3+y^3+z^3=a^3} \frac{\bf{x}}{||\bf{x}||} \cdot d\bf{S}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, parametric, surface-integrals

Compute the surface integral: $$\int_S({x\over \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}, {y\over \sqrt{ x^2+y^2+z^2}}, {z\over \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}) \cdot \vec n \ dS$$

where $S: x^3+y^3+z^3=a^3$

The first parametrization that came to my mind was: $r(x,y)=(x,y,(a^3-x^3-y^3)^{1/3})$ but the integral becomes very hard to compute; I also gave

$$r(u,v)=(a(\cos(u)\sin(v))^{2/3},a(\sin(u)\sin(v))^{2/3},a(\cos(v))^{2/3})$$

(I was thinking about some type of spherical transformation) but then again the integral becomes vey hard to compute. Can you please help me with this problem? I would really appreciate it :)

Comment: Oh good god. I can't help but this seems really cruel to me. I would think spherical coordinates would be best, but then your surface would be really strangely parameterized. This is one of the things I absolutely abhor about multivariable calculus. Professors think it's cute to give these really obnoxious problems that don't test understanding but rather they test your patience.

Comment: I guess you can use divergent theorem..... (Not sure if it will be easier then)

Comment: I don´t know, I´m almost sure that there is a parametrization that simplifies everything (I think I´m being optimistic)

Comment: @copper.hat I think so, but the surface isn't closed, it's an unbounded surface separating the space into two regions. One can still try something by intersecting one region with a large ball... but before doing that I'd go to the author of the problem to ask what they were thinking.

Comment: @copper.hat the equation has cubes, intentionally or not...

Comment: @Yes: Wow, I missed that completely. Deleting irrelevant remarks.

Comment: Yes, it is an unbounded region it´s like $x^{1/3}$ but in $\mathbb R^3$

Comment: This surface is known as the Fermat Cubic: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_cubic. Wikipedia gives a parameterization, but I'm not sure if it makes things easier.

Comment: @PeterFranek, you are right! I didn´t see that the field is actually $\vec n$

Comment: I suggest page 127-128 of Spivak "Calculus on Manifolds"; he is a very clear writer.  Except you are integrating a scalar; the projection of the normal onto the radial vector.  Thus you should have a scaler times the differential of the surface area.

Comment: Did you find the solution of this question? I am interested to know! :)

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer. I did some progress and convert the surface integral into an improper double integral. So anyone willing to find a solution may use the final result in this post.

Your surface for $a=1$ and ratio $1:1:1$ between the $x$, $y$, and $z$ axis looks like this

$\qquad \qquad \qquad \,\,$[image]

so it is not a closed surface and we cannot use the divergence theorem as it was mentioned in the comments too. Next, note that

$$\begin{array}{}
g(x,y,z)=x^3+y^3+z^3-a^3 \\
{\bf{F}} = \frac{\bf{x}}{\left\| {\bf{x}} \right\|}= {x\over \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}{\bf{i}} + {y\over \sqrt{ x^2+y^2+z^2}} {\bf{j}} + {z\over \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}} {\bf{k}} \\
{d\bf{S}}= {1 \over {\partial{g} \over \partial z}} \nabla g \, dx dy \\
{1 \over {\partial{g} \over \partial z}}\nabla g=\frac{1}{z^2}(x^2 {\bf{i}} + y^2 {\bf{j}} + z^2 {\bf{k})} \\
{\bf{F}} \cdot {d\bf{S}} = \frac{x^3+y^3+z^3}{z^2 \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}} dx dy =  \frac{a^3}{z^2 \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}} dx dy\\
\end{array}$$

and finally the surface integral becomes

$$\iint_{S} {\bf{F}} \cdot {d\bf{S}} = \int_{x=-\infty}^{+\infty} \int_{y=-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{a^3}{z^2 \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}dydx \tag{*}$$

and note that $z$ is a function of $x$ and $y$ by the relation

$$z=(a^3-x^3-y^3)^{\frac{1}{3}}$$

Now, one may work on $(*)$ to obtain some result.